# MySQL 1064 syntax erroe

Tags: sql, mysql

I am importing a sql file into a `MySQL` database, but it imports half tables, after there is an error at this table:

```
    DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `v_deals`;

CREATE TABLE `v_deals` (
   `LocationCode` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `LocationName` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   `LocationTypeID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
   `Address` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `City` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `Province` VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `TelephoneNumber` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   `www` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   `eMail` VARCHAR(40) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   `LocationDescription` VARCHAR(256) NULL DEFAULT '',
   `ZipCode` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `Latitude` DOUBLE(10) NOT NULL,
   `Longitude` DOUBLE(10) NOT NULL,
   `NumberRating` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   `PercentRating` DECIMAL(33) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   `Miniatura` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   `Title` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `SubTitle` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT '',
   `Text` VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `PhotoUrl` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT '',
   `Created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
   `CountryCode` VARCHAR(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   `DealsID` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

the error is:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') NOT NULL,
   `Longitude` DOUBLE(10) NOT NULL,
   `NumberRating` BIGINT(20) N' at line 13
```

Comment: `double` needs either no argument or two. There is no definition with just one argument.

Comment: Further down the road, prefixing a table with "v_" is liable to cause confusion. Also, I wonder if DECIMAL is more appropriate.

Comment: why v_ cause confusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the columns of DOUBLE type, you should provide the number of decimal you want Ex : DOUBLE(10,2)

Comment: aaah...yes...10,2 two numbers after , ..yes, now it works thanks!